# Unable to create a new instance of a Backbone View

Tags: javascript, oop, backbone.js, multiple-instances, backbone-views

I have a "master" view, a layout if you will, that loads other views through the `loadView` method. My problem is that these view classes perform some initialisation logic (in `initialize`) that can only be performed once (to do with templating). If, however, I try and instantiate these classes more than once, I get an error symptomatic of calling initialize on the same instance.

I have tried, in the console, instantiating them separately by loading the class and creating two new instances using `var x = new MyViewClass();` but each time the first one instantiates and the second one fails because of this error caused by the templates already being initialised.

This really shouldn't be happening, but I cannot for the life of me see what is causing the problem.

The layout's loading code is below.

```
loadView: function(name, bootstrap_function) {
    this.unloadView();

    var _class  = require('View/'+name),                // Let's load the view file
        pretty  = name.replace('/', ''),                // Prettify the name by removing slashes (should end up with some camelcased niceness)
        bs_name = '__bootstrap'+pretty,                 // Generate the name of the bootstrap function
        view    = new _class();                         // Pass the event aggregator in

    // If there is a bootstrap function, bootstrap
    if(typeOf(bootstrap_function) == 'function') {      // Check if one has been passed in
        bootstrap_function.call(this, view);            // Bootstrap: function(AppView, LoadedView)
    }

    this._loaded = view;                                // Store the view in _loaded

    // Now that we have a view to play with
    // we should insert it into our container object
    view.$el.appendTo(this.$container);

    // And render!
    view.render();
},

unloadView: function() {
    if(this._loaded !== null) {
        this._loaded.remove();
        this._loaded.unbind();
        this._loaded = null;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

The templating code that is having the errors is this:

```
processTemplates: function() {
    if(this.templates === undefined) return this;

    console.log(this.templates);

    if(Object.getLength(this.templates) > 0) {
        Object.each(this.templates, function(template, name) {
            this.templates[name] = _.template(template);
        }, this);
    }

    return this;
},
```

The `console.log(this.templates)` output shows that on the first initialisation, `this.templates` contains strings, as it should, but on second initialisation it shows template functions (which should only be the case after `processTemplates()` is called.

I wonder if it could have anything to do with the way my class is defined, for example:

```
define(
    ['backbone', 'View/Kords', 'text!Template/Pages/Landing.html', 'Collection/TenantTypes'],
    function(Backbone, KordsView, landing_html, TenantTypesCollection) {
        var LandingView = KordsView.extend({
            tagName: 'div',
            className: 'tiled-light',

            templates: {
                'main': landing_html
            },
```

`landing_html` is defined like this in the class, but could there be a reference problem? `_.template` should not be affecting the value of `landing_html` within the scope, should it?

**EDIT #2**

It is not to do with the reference to landing_html. I tried just setting templates.main to a string in the class definition but I still got the errors as before.

Comment: you sure multiple requiring of same file is ok?

Comment: Requiring the same file twice should just return the class declaration, not an instance. My classes are constructed using `KordsView.extend({})` (I have a lot of logic that I use in all my views stored in KordsView, including the templating logic).

Comment: I have tried storing the `_class` variable so I don't call `require` twice if it has been called before, but it makes no difference. This makes sense because I believe that require caches the file anyway.

Comment: Initialize is always going to be called on every `new _class()` call so you'll need to set up your initialize to only set up the template once. Can you show an example of the template logic you are having trouble with?

Comment: Of course initialize will be called on class instantiation, but all the instance properties (like templates: {}) should also be re-instantiated. I'll edit my question with the bit of code that is troublesome.